# How can I make a solid shift hue over time in python?

Tags: python, numpy, colors, tkinter, hue

I am trying to create a solid that changes hue over time, but I'm a bit confused as to how I should do it. I'm currently making an attempt with the Tkinter module in python, but it only supports hex and colors based off words. Ideally I would be able to adjust HSV values and simply add a time expression to the hue, but it seems as if that might be difficult considering Tkinter's color input system. I've seen people recommending using the colorsys module but it's slow to process apparently and I don't know how well it would hold up to shifting the hue ~30 times per second.

Comment: Have you considered generating a lookup table?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to convert HSL into RGB first. Here's a solution I found from another question on SO:

```
def hueToRgb(p, q, t):
    if t < 0: t += 1
    if t > 1: t -= 1
    if t < 1/6: return p + (q - p) * 6 * t
    if t < 1/2: return q
    else: return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6 ift < 2/3 else p

def hslToRgb(h, s, l):
    r = 0
    g = 0
    b = 0

    if s == 0:
        r = g = b = l
    else:
        q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s
        p = 2 * l - q
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3)
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h)
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3)
    return [round(r * 255), round(g * 255), round(b * 255)]
```

Then, to convert HSL into a valid hex code use this code (This is my own code):

```
def hex(num):
    if num == 0: return "#"
    last = num % 16
    return hex((num - last) / 16) + "0123456789abcdef"[int(last)]
```

So you would use this code to get the hex string for HSL code:

```
rgb = hslToRgb(h, s, l)
return hex(rgb[0] * 256 + rgb[1] * 16 + rgb[0])
```

(Please correct any python syntax errors; I don't program with Python a lot)

Comment: The `colorsys` module can do conversions to/from RGB and hue-based color spaces.